# --skip-grant-tables option cannot execute statement

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a mysql database via the CLI when I run this 
command line

```
Create user meriemPFE;
```

he made me get this error message, which I could not resolve.

> the server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option can not execute this statement.

EDIT:

yes I put it in the file C: \ xampp \ mysql \ bin \ my.ini

this is a portion of code

```
[mysqld]

skip-grant-tables
port= 3306
socket = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
tmpdir = "C:/xampp/tmp" 
datadir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data" 
pid_file = "mysql.pid"
```

Comment: Did you intentionally set `--skip-grant-tables` on?

Comment: Try `CREATE USER meriemPFE IDENTIFIED BY SomePassword;`

Comment: yes I put it in the file C: \ xampp \ mysql \ bin \ my.ini

this is a portion of code ' [mysqld]
skip-grant-tables
port= 3306
socket = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"'

Comment: and i tried CREATE USER meriemPFE IDENTIFIED BY SomePassword; , same error message

Comment: WHY are you using `skip-grant-tables` It shoudl only be used for specific situations like recovering a lost root password. It is INCREDIBLY insecure to run with this set for normal processing as anybody is allowed to login without any password or credential checking

Comment: I added that to your question. Using the `edit` link under your question. That is also what you should use in the furture. specially if a comment contains any code. As it is almost unnreadable in a comment :)

Comment: I use it to fix access denied for user

Comment: It is simpler just to use `phpMyAdmin` or the `mysql.exe` to reset a password. Only use this IF its the `root` user account that you have lost the password for.

Answer (score 0):

In `mysql`, verify executing the `flush privileges` command.

> mysql> flush privileges

This action solved the error in my case.

> the server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option can not
> execute this statement.

I hope this helps you too. Health!

Answer (score 0):

As of recent versions of MySQL/MariaDB starting with `--skip-grant-tables` doesn't work to reset the mysql `root` user password.

As per [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html) you now need a different process to reset the mysql `root` user.

Assuming a Linux machine running MariaDB as `root` (if not get root with `sudo su root`).

Then create a file somewhere that the `mysql` user can read. I use `/var/lib/mysql/mysql-init` (but it can be anywhere really). In that file put the following:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
```

(Obviously change `MyNewPass` to be your desired password).

As noted the `mysql` user must have read access to this file. To ensure no other users can read it I recommend chowning it and set permissions to read only for all other users. I.e.:

```
chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/mysql-init
chmod 0400 /var/lib/mysql/mysql-init
```

Then stop MariaDB, assuming systemd:

```
systemctl stop mariadb
```

Then start it again from CLI:

```
mysqld --init-file=/var/lib/mysql/mysql-init &
```

(note other options may be required, but just like that works for me)

Once it has successfully started, then kill it again:

```
kill $(pgrep mysqld)
```

And restart the service:

```
systemctl start mariadb
```

And you should be good to go with your new password!

I also suggest cleaning up the `mysql-init` file:

```
rm /var/lib/mysql/mysql-init
```

If like me you want to change to use the `unix_socket` then:

```
mysql -e "ALTER USER root@localhost IDENTIFIED VIA 'unix_socket';"
```