unable to find /root/.my.cnf. Exception message: (1698, \"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'\")
I'm trying to create and environment with Ansible to Wordpress with MariaDB, but i'm getting almost the same errors while trying to create the database and to create a new user with privileges on Oracle Linux (9.4) or Fedora (40).
The inventory is:
[fedora]
192.168.1.200 ansible_ssh_user=leo hostname=fedorasrv01 

[oracle]
192.168.1.202 ansible_ssh_user=leo hostname=oraclesrv01

This is the ansible playbook:
- name: Install Mariadb Server - RedHat
  yum:
    name:
      - mariadb-server
      - python3-pip
    state: present
  when: (ansible_facts['os_family'] == "RedHat")

- name: Install PyMySQL on RedHat
  ansible.builtin.pip:
    name: PyMySQL
    state: present
  when: (ansible_facts['os_family'] == "RedHat")

- name: "Start MariaDB"
  service:
    name: mariadb
    state: started
    enabled: yes

- name: Creating a database to be used by WordPress - RedHat
  mysql_db:
    name: "{{ db_wp_name }}"
    state: present
  when: (ansible_facts['os_family'] == "RedHat")

- name: Create user with password, all database privileges - RedHat
  mysql_user:
    name: "{{ db_wp_username }}"
    password: "{{ db_wp_password }}"
    priv: "{{ db_wp_name }}.*:ALL,GRANT"
    state: present
  when: (ansible_facts['os_family'] == "RedHat")

These are the errors:
TASK [mysql : Creating a database to be used by WordPress - RedHat] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [192.168.1.202]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "unable to find /root/.my.cnf. Exception message: (1698, \"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'\")"}
fatal: [192.168.1.200]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "unable to find /root/.my.cnf. Exception message: (1045, \"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)\")"}

During the seek, I tried to use another yml to help, calling it before the step that broke the pipeline.
- name: Stop MySQL
  service: name=mysqld state=stopped
- name: set environment variables
  shell: systemctl set-environment MYSQLD_OPTS="--skip-grant-tables"
- name: Start MySQL
  service: name=mysqld state=started
- name: sql query
  command:  mysql -u root --execute="UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('{{ mysql_root_password }}') WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';"
- name: sql query flush
  command:  mysql -u root --execute="FLUSH PRIVILEGES"
- name: Stop MySQL
  service: name=mysqld state=stopped
- name: unset environment variables
  shell: systemctl unset-environment MYSQLD_OPTS
- name: Start MySQL
  service: name=mysqld state=started

But after this, the errors now are:
TASK [mysql : sql query] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [192.168.1.200]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["mysql", "-u", "root", "--execute=UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('Password123') WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';"], "delta": "0:00:00.087770", "end": "2024-07-02 07:06:47.621171", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2024-07-02 07:06:47.533401", "stderr": "ERROR 1348 (HY000) at line 1: Column 'authentication_string' is not updatable", "stderr_lines": ["ERROR 1348 (HY000) at line 1: Column 'authentication_string' is not updatable"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
fatal: [192.168.1.202]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["mysql", "-u", "root", "--execute=UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('Password123') WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';"], "delta": "0:00:00.088495", "end": "2024-07-02 07:06:47.591159", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2024-07-02 07:06:47.502664", "stderr": "ERROR 1348 (HY000) at line 1: Column 'authentication_string' is not updatable", "stderr_lines": ["ERROR 1348 (HY000) at line 1: Column 'authentication_string' is not updatable"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

After this try, i commented the help.yml and tried again, and apparently the db creation worked, but still having problems with the permissions. Now the errors are:
TASK [mysql : Create user with password, all database privileges - RedHat] *********************************
fatal: [192.168.1.202]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "(1290, 'The MariaDB server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement')"}
fatal: [192.168.1.200]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "(1290, 'The MariaDB server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement')"}

I just tried what this post said (--skip-grant-tables option cannot execute statement) with mysql user, this msg is shwon:
mysql: unknown variable 'init-file=/var/lib/mysql/mysql-init'

I just tried to find the socket too, but on RedHat family i did not find it to use, i don't know if it's needed some configuration to do that.

I just tried what this post said (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54751024/skip-grant-tables-option-cannot-execute-statement) with mysql user, this msg is shwon:
mysql: unknown variable 'init-file=/var/lib/mysql/mysql-init'


Storing credentials in /root/.my.cnf is a small security risk. If this is a fresh install then root@localhost should have a unix_socket authentication not requiring this file. Maybe the ansible module is old. Or something MariaDB focused/tested would be better.
The mysql.user is not there to be directly manipulated.
To reset back after your --skip-grant-tables step:
mariadb -u root --execute="FLUSH PRIVILEGES; ALTER USER root@localhost IDENTIFIED WITH unix_socket"

Or if you really want a password, do both:
mariadb -u root --execute="FLUSH PRIVILEGES; ALTER USER root@localhost  IDENTIFIED VIA mysql_native_password AS PASSWORD('secret') OR unix_socket "


I just tried to use both, and still having the same problems on db creation.

It's a fresh installation and the ansible and it's modules are latest versions.

latest docs indicate that ~/.my.cnf is only read if it exists, which seems contradictory to "unable to find /root/.my.cnf".

leo@fedorasrv01:~$ sudo cat /root/.my.cnf
cat: /root/.my.cnf: Arquivo ou diretório inexistente
leo@fedorasrv01:~$ sudo cat ~/.my.cnf
cat: /home/leo/.my.cnf: Arquivo ou diretório inexistente

[leo@oraclesrv01 ~]$ sudo cat /root/.my.cnf
cat: /root/.my.cnf: No such file or directory
[leo@oraclesrv01 ~]$ sudo cat ~/.my.cnf
cat: /home/leo/.my.cnf: No such file or directory
